# how to share a link via sms in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, sms

I am building an application where I need the option to share via email and SMS.

I have done the share via Email, where when the user selects the image, the url is passed as the content of the email. But while sharing via SMS, I can't do something like `setContent` as I did for email and fetch the url in the SMS directly, instead of user typing the address manually.

I am using Message class in email and MessageConnection class for SMS, as shown in the blackberry community example.

Answer (score 0):

The Message object you receive when calling MessageConnection.newMessage(TEXT_MESSAGE) is actually a TextMessage object (or a BinaryMessage object with BINARY_MESSAGE).

If you cast the received object to the proper class (TextMessage or BinaryMessage), you should be able to use its setPayloadText(String data) (or setPayloadData(byte[] data) for a BinaryMessage) to enter a value in the message before sending it.

Your code should look like this:

```
Message msg = myMessageConnection.newMessage(TEXT_MESSAGE, /* address */);
TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage)msg;
txtMsg.setPayloadText(/* Text to send */);
myMessageConnection.send(msg);
```

Comment: I will say, though, that I never coded for Blackberry. This is entirely based on the RIM documentation. Caveat emptor

Answer (score 0):

When you send an email, you can set the body of it and send it to the user from the Email native application. You cant do taht for SMSs. I worked on that issue and for BB Torch I was able to set the text of the SMS message but for other devices that was impossible. I always obtain an empty text message!!

So y suggestion to you is using the following code wich will send the SMS to a number without the interference of the user

```
MessageConnection conn = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://" + userNumber);
TextMessage txtmessage = (TextMessage) conn.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
txtmessage.setPayloadText(text);
conn.send(txtmessage);
```